# How do I use semaphore as share variable (share memory) in Producer/Consumer problem in C

Tags: c, semaphore, shared-memory, producer-consumer

I have been trying to use semaphore in my producer/consumer problem but I couldn't figure out how to declare semaphore and mutex lock in shared memory and use them across two processes. My current program is not working correctly but I attach them here. Please give me suggestions and thank you in advance.

producer.c

```
#include "protocol.h"

// producer Code
static const char name[] = "sem";

void producer(struct ShmData *shmData, sem_t *sem) {
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(sem);
        // If mutex is 1 and buffer is not full, then it is
        // possible to produce
        if ((shmData->mutex == 1) && (shmData->empty != 0)) {
            // Producer code starts here
            // Decrease mutex value by 1
            shmData->mutex = (shmData->mutex)-1; // mutex--

            // Decrease the number of buffer by 1
            shmData->full = (shmData->full) + 1; //full++
            shmData->empty = (shmData->empty) - 1; //empty--
          
            // Item produced
            shmData->x = (shmData->x) + 1; //x++
            printf("\nProducer produces item %d", shmData->x);
          
            // Increase mutex value by 1
            shmData->mutex = (shmData->mutex) + 1; //mutex++

            // Producer code ends here
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    sem_unlink(name);
    sem_t *sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, 0);
    if( sem == SEM_FAILED ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "sem_open");
    }

    int fd = shm_open(NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0600); 
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("shm_open() producer error"); 
        close(fd); 
        shm_unlink(NAME); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }

    ftruncate(fd, SIZE); 
    struct ShmData *shmData = mmap(0, sizeof(*shmData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 

    shmData->mutex = 1; // mutual exclusion
    shmData->full  = 0; 
    shmData->empty = BUFFER;
    shmData->x     = 0; // Item number

    pthread_t th[THREAD_NUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &producer, shmData) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to join thread");
        }
    }
    
    munmap(shmData, SIZE); 
    close(fd); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

consumer.c

```
/* https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-problem-in-c/ */

#include "protocol.h"
  
// consumer Code 
void consumer(struct ShmData *shmData) {
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++) {
        sleep(2); 
        // If mutex is 1 and buffer is not empty, then it is
        // possible to consume

        if ((shmData->mutex == 1) && (shmData->full != 0)) {
            // consumer code starts here
            // Decrease mutex value by 1
            shmData->mutex = (shmData->mutex) - 1; // mutex--
          
            // Increase the number of empty
            // slots by 1
            shmData->full = (shmData->full) - 1; // full--;
            shmData->empty = (shmData->empty) + 1; // empty++;

            printf("\nConsumer consumes item %d", shmData->x);
            shmData->x = (shmData->x) - 1; // x--;
          
            // Increase mutex value by 1
            shmData->mutex = (shmData->mutex) + 1; // mutex++;
            // consumer code ends here
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    sleep(1);
    int fd = shm_open(NAME, O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0600); 
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("shm_open() consumer error"); 
        close(fd); 
        shm_unlink(NAME); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }

    ftruncate(fd, SIZE); 
    struct ShmData *shmData = mmap(0, sizeof(*shmData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 

    pthread_t th[THREAD_NUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &consumer, shmData) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to join thread");
        }
    }

    munmap(shmData, SIZE); 
    close(fd); 
    shm_unlink(NAME); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

protocol.h

```
#ifndef PROTOCOL_H
#define PROTOCOL_H

#define NAME "/pcp-sharemem"
#define NUM 4
#define SIZE (NUM * sizeof(int))
#define BUFFER 2
#define THREAD_NUM 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <err.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>

struct ShmData {
    int mutex; 
    int full; 
    int empty; 
    int x; 
};

#endif /* PROTOCOL_H */
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain "*not working correctly*". What input do you use (if any), what output or behavior do you expect and what output or behavior do you actually get? A variable in shared memory cannot be used as a mutex without other synchronization mechanisms. For example one thread could be interrupted by another between checking the `mutex` value and modifying it and the other can have modified it in between. You use `sem_post` but I don't see `sem_wait` anywhere. I suggest to describe your concept how the synchronization and communication between the threads should work

Comment: Please see my additional information.